# Query Column of Specific ID from Database Table

Tags: database, query, mysql, wpdb

I am trying to display a particular value from the WordPress database for a specific ID with no such luck. I am not receiving any errors, but just an empty result. Here is my table:

```
table name: _customtable

id     item_key     item_value
1      url          https://mywebsite.com
2      techurl      https://awsinstnaceid.production.mywebsite.com
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use to display the techurl value in item_value

```
global $wpdb; 
$table_name = $wpdb->_customtable; 
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE 'id'= 2" ); 
foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {  
echo $retrieved_data->item_value;  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 two problems here:
- You can't use $wpdb-> with custom tables because [postmeta, posts, ...] are variables in the class $wpdb.
- WHERE 'id'= 2 is not correct WHERE id = 2

So it should work:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = "_customtable";
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id = 2" );
foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {
    echo $retrieved_data->item_value;  }
```

Regards.